# Replacing WIndows 8.1 within Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I am in the process of wiping my Windows 8.1 install and replace it with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but have the following queries pls, prior to doing anything:

1) Will I be able to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my new Acer Aspire ES1-512 C32A laptop, which is a 64 bit OS, has 8GB RAM (upgraded it) and a 500GB HDD (7200rpm). Boot mode is set to: UEFI?

2) I have created a USB Flash drive install of Ubuntu using Universal Installer app - I believe it worked, even though it was stuck on 99% but when I pressed "Close" after 15 mins, it came back saying installation completed successfully - can I assumed this worked or can people suggest another installer ISO app?

3) When I restart my laptop and press the F2 key to enter BIOS mode, I switch over to Boot section and I  am presented with Boot Mode of UEFI  and then the option set boot sequence of drives, which would be my USB drive. My question is, what should the Boot Mode be when I go to change the boot order sequence - should it be **UEFI** or **Legacy**?

4) If/when I eventually wipe Windows 8.1 and replace with Ubuntu, is there any special I need to do from my end?

5)Will things like Wireless LAN | SD Card Reader| Touchpad  work straight off the bat or do I need to install specific drivers?

Have I missed any other crucial steps?

Furthermore, I actually have another laptop that I use for all things Windows 8.1 and so I want to dedicate this Acer laptop alone to just being a linux box. Am not interested in dual boot on Acer.

Thanks.

Comment: before you whipe, go install Vmware migration tools and make a virtual image of your windows8 machine. Youll have the option to compress it, so do that. Then once you have installed linux, you can still use your old OS simulaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Many users find one application or game that they just cannot live without and then want to restore Windows & dual boot. Best to have good backups of efi partition and full Windows install.

How you boot install media UEFI or CSM/BIOS is how it installs. And then that is the setting you have to have in UEFI. Best to use UEFI.

Acer Aspire ES1-512-C39M Details on password and settings to enable trust on ubuntu entries

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256083&p=13203044#post13203044

http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27071/~/how-to-enable-or-disable-secure-boot

Aspire E1-522 InsydeH20 Bios unlock -  7 min video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SkBFkzOW0A

Acer E1-531 UEFI menus.
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/65627-63-body

Did live installer work in live mode? That tells best if it will work without added effort to install extra/special drivers.

Comment: Pls see my updated thread above re: not interested in dual boot - just a dedicated Linux box. Thanks.

Comment: Are you installing in UEFI or BIOS mode. This shows screens you may see:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Will be installing in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 1):

- first of all, you need to be sure that you have the 64 bit Ubuntu installer and not the 32 bit.
  You can get it at

http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/

http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso

- next, you have to make a live usb of ubuntu:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

- then, change the IDE to your flash drive and boot from it
- then, install Ubuntu alongside windows.
- if you have problems with your partitioning, pick "try Ubuntu" in the beggining of your installation and open gparted partition editor. then, check and fix the windows partition.
- if you get all this done, you should have grub and dual-boot on your computer

Note: if my answer solved your problem, dont forget to tick the check mark next to the answer.

ENJOY!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I definitely have the 64 bit version of Ubuntu, but I am not requiring dual boot. I want to dedicate this Acer laptop to being a 100% linux box - no MS Windows 8.1 required. Is this possible with the Ubuntu Installation process within Live USB - try Ubuntu before installing? Thanks.

Comment: in that case, since your windows partition is causing the problem, opn gparted(in try ubuntu mode), then delete the windows partition. and then you can install Ubuntu fully on your computer with the option " erase disk and install ubuntu

Comment: Hi - have actually done this but having issues with shim efi key component. See my other thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to install ubuntu inside windows8.1 and make your PC dual boot
thats will help you to do any thing in both system

you can see here :
[Dual-Boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8 "2014"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uVcsFhv2Vo)

Answer (score 0):

**First** Go to [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) and read everything very carefully. Even though the answers are for dualboot, you can choose to wipe Windows and replace it with Ubuntu at the time of installation.

**To answer your questions...**

1) *Will I be able to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my new Acer Aspire ES1-512 C32A laptop, which is a 64 bit OS, has 8GB RAM (upgraded it) and a 500GB HDD (7200rpm). Boot mode is set to: UEFI?*

This is hard to say as computer manufacturers often use different internal components for different batches of the computer with same model number. The best thing to do is to boot from the Live USB you created and select **"Try Ubuntu without installing"**. This option will not make any changes to your computer and you will be able to check if everything works or not.

2) *I have created a USB Flash drive install of Ubuntu using Universal Installer app - I believe it worked, even though it was stuck on 99% but when I pressed "Close" after 15 mins, it came back saying installation completed successfully - can I assumed this worked or can people suggest another installer ISO app?*

Try the Live USB without installing as mentioned above. If it does not work, try creating the Live USB again.

3) *When I restart my laptop and press the F2 key to enter BIOS mode, I switch over to Boot section and I am presented with Boot Mode of UEFI and then the option set boot sequence of drives, which would be my USB drive. My question is, what should the Boot Mode be when I go to change the boot order sequence - should it be UEFI or Legacy?*

For a system that just boots Ubuntu, it does not matter if you choose UEFI or Legacy. The installation program will use the appropriate process. If you intend to use UEFI, at the time you choose the Boot drive, make sure you choose the USB with UEFI.

4) *If/when I eventually wipe Windows 8.1 and replace with Ubuntu, is there any special I need to do from my end?*

If you select the option to replace Windows with Ubuntu during installation, it will erase everything in your hard drive including other partitions such as `D:\`. If you have data, music, photos, etc. in another partition, copy them in an external drive before you start. You may also choose "Something Else..." and manually select the partitions for Ubuntu. This requires some knowledge of the partition scheme used by Ubuntu.

5)*Will things like Wireless LAN | SD Card Reader| Touchpad work straight off the bat or do I need to install specific drivers?*

Most things should work. Ubuntu has most drivers already built in. The two exceptions are graphics cards and WiFi cards. Even for these opensource drivers are built-in. If your WiFi card needs a proprietary driver, you connect your computer by Ethernet during installation and check the appropriate box to install these additional drivers at the install time. This can be also done later by running the appropriate program that looks for and installs additional drivers if they are needed.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answers. FYI, I am currently writing this comment using the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option and all seems to be working fine. WiFi, graphics card and touchpad. Not sure yet about SD card reader yet. Based on this, I am confident that Ubuntu 14.04 works on  my Acer Aspire ES1 512 laptop. If I install Ubuntu and overwrite my HDD with new Ubuntu, is there  anything else I need to do afterwards?

Comment: I will certainly do this after I have officially installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. Just want to keep it open until I know all works fine. Just want to keep running with the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like I just found an issue with Live USB - my system doesn't seem to shutdown. Just shows me the Ubuntu Logo in centre of screen.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/search?q=%22not+shutdown%22 for possible solution. If not, ask a new question.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/585134/what-should-i-do-straight-after-installing-ubuntu for what you may want to do after intalling Ubuntu.